# Django: Order Queryset so single record is last

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, django-queryset

I want the order of my queryset to be such that I have a single record as the last and then all other records above them ordered a different way.

For example, a models.py in an app named agency...

```
class Agency(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name or "No Name"
```

There is one record with id 12 that I want to have at the bottom of the queryset and all of the others ordered above by name, so the SQL would translate to something like this (Note, "id" == 12 would be True for Agency 12 and False for all others, so that first ordering statement would make all non-12 agencies above since False > True in PostgreSQL anyway):

```
SELECT
        "agency_agency"."id",
        "agency_agency"."name"
FROM
        "agency_agency"
ORDER BY
        "agency_agency"."id" = '12',
        "agency_agency"."name"
```

So, how do I accomplish this with Django Querysets?

```
agencies = Agency.objects.all().order_by(
    'id=12',
    'name'
) >>> Just throws Field errors
```

**UPDATE**

**I just figured out how to solve with the `.extra()` method as such:**

```
agencies = Agency.objects.all().extra(
    order_by[
        '"agency_agency"."id" = 12',
        'name'
    ]
)
```

Does anybody know how to solve this without the use of the `.extra()` method?

Comment: try this `Agency.objects.exclude(id=12).order_by("name")`. I don't know it's works or not (:..

Comment: Thanks for the response, but if I run `.exclude(id=12)` the WHERE statement will say `"agency_agency"."id" != '12'` and I won't have it in my final QuerySet. I want to include it, but want it as my last record.